# Mutual nodes order by occurrence orientdb

Tags: gremlin, orientdb, orientdb3.0, orient-sql

I'm trying to perform the following graph query in orientdb and it works

```
select nearTo as c1,nearTo.id,nearTo.name, count(nearTo) as repetition,level,path  from ( 
  MATCH {class: GNode, where: (id = 5)} 
  -has-> {as: connection, while: ($depth <= 1), where: ($depth <= 1)}  
  -has-> {as: nearTo, while: ($depth < 3), where: ($depth > 1), depthAlias: level,pathAlias: path} 
  RETURN nearTo,level,path
)
group by nearTo order by repetition desc
```

The problem with this query is that it matches the nodes in the connection too if connection flows back, so i tried the following queries and none worked

```
1) 
select nearTo,nearTo.id,nearTo.name, count(nearTo) as repetition,level,path  from ( 
  MATCH {class: GNode, where: (id = 5)} 
  -has-> {as: connection, while: ($depth < 2), where: ($depth <= 1)}  
  -has-> {as: nearTo, while: ($depth < 4), where: ($depth > 1), depthAlias: level,pathAlias: path} 
  
  RETURN nearTo,level,path
) where nearTo not in [connection]
group by nearTo order by repetition desc

2) 
select nearTo,nearTo.id,nearTo.name, count(nearTo) as repetition,level,path  from ( 
  MATCH {class: GNode, where: (id = 5)} 
  -has-> {as: connection, while: ($depth < 2), where: ($depth <= 1)}  
  -has-> {as: nearTo, while: ($depth < 4), where: ($depth > 1), depthAlias: level,pathAlias: path} 
  
  RETURN nearTo,level,path
) where nearTo not in [(MATCH {class: GNode, where: (id = 5)} 
  -has-> {as: c, while: ($depth < 2), where: ($depth <= 1)} RETURN c)]
group by nearTo order by repetition desc

3) 
select nearToFinal,nearToFinal.id,nearToFinal.name, count(nearToFinal) as repetition,level,path  from ( 
  MATCH {class: GNode, where: (id = 5)} 
  -has-> {as: connection, while: ($depth < 2), where: ($depth <= 1)}  
  -has-> {as: nearTo, while: ($depth < 4), where: ($depth > 1), depthAlias: level,pathAlias: path} 
   -has-> NOT {as:nearToFinal}
  RETURN nearToFinal,level,path
)
group by nearToFinal order by repetition desc
```

Alternatively the below query gives me the negated result, but unable to order based on repetition as alias not supported for from clause

```
select * from (TRAVERSE out("has") FROM #27:1 MAXDEPTH 4 STRATEGY BREADTH_FIRST) where @rid NOT IN (TRAVERSE out("has") FROM #27:1 MAXDEPTH 1)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Same case with gremlin query is also fine.